# Expression for an intersection of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have two series, one of the form $S_1=u(u+1)$ and another of the form $S_2=u(13u\pm 1)$, which leads to $S_1=2,6,12,20,...$ and $S_2=
...,114,50,12,0,14,54,120,...$. Then a third series is formed given by $S_3=S_1 \cap S_2$, meaning $S_3=12,462,54990,...$. I would like to know if $S_3$ can be expressed in terms of $u$?